# Make a DOS batch script to rename between word of files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'm currently stuck on an issue with a DOS batch script I’ve been working on, and I need help renaming the files.

Here is the renaming scheme I’m searching for:

Original filenames are more than 30. I wrote only 4.
For example, what do I do for put "kyt-" before last words?

all file name : pajiro kart 05 abd.txt

results: : pajiro kart 05 kyt-abd.txt

or

all file name : pajiro kart 05 acd.txt

results: : pajiro kart 05 kyt-acd.txt

Comment: comment me after you have done the following: put all the filenames into your question so we only have to do this once: `dir /b pajiro* > files.txt`

Comment: add all filenames to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit

How to rename files with a cmd for loop. How to insert a string into a filename using a cmd for loop.

cmd:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %a in ('dir /b pajiro*') do ren "%a %b" "%a kyt-%b"
```

script:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ('dir /b pajiro*') do ren "%%a %%b" "%%a kyt-%%b"
exit /b
```

test files:

```
pajiro abd
pajiro adc
pajiro acc
pajiro ahc
```

results:

```
pajiro kyt-abd
pajiro kyt-acc
pajiro kyt-adc
pajiro kyt-ahc
```

Comment: it's work but If have space in words not work how can I rename with words that have space?

Example: pajiro kart 05

results: : pajiro kart 05 kyt-abd

pajiro kart 05 ==> pajiro kart 05 kyt-abd

Comment: added all file names to question. please answer now

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer